# Does Visual Studio officially support "%lld" format specifier for __int64?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, format-specifiers, long-long

According to this document
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6(v=vs.140).aspx programmers should printf **long long** variables with **%lld** and **__int64** variables with **%I64d**.

And according to this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx  **__int64** is just another name for **long long**.

Then why doesn't the first document just say that **%lld** can be used for **__int64** too? Does VS team think that in future **__int64** will be different than **long long**? I cannot imagine how this will happen if they care about backward compatibility...

Thank you

Comment: They want to keep the option open - after all `int` also used to be 16bit in times past. Also it makes your intentions clearer

Comment: I remember when an `int` was 16-bit. In 64-bit, Microsoft went with a 32-bit `long` (for compatibility) while everyone else increased it to 64-bit.

Comment: The first page you link to has a "not maintained" disclaimer on the top because it documents a 12-year-old version of the compiler and libraries.  The up-to-date page goes into a little more detail.  But it boils down to the fact that `%lld` is part of the C++ standard (which Microsoft doesn't control) and `%I64d` is a Microsoft extension (which they do control).  Although unlikely, it's conceivable that `long long int` and `__int64` could diverge in the future.  For example, perhaps someday one will be required to be two's complement and the other signed magnitude.

Comment: Updated the first link, thanks. Okay, I see the point. Let's just hope they won't need to diverge these types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VS does support `%lld` for `long long` starting from VS2013 (`_MSC_VER` >= 1800).
See [msdn documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2015#size-prefixes-for-printf-and-wprintf-format-type-specifiers) for supported printf specifiers.

Even though `__int64` "requires" `I64` according to their docs, however, `__int64` is the same as or convertible to `long long` and works without warnings.